# Disable .NET Framework 4.8 Advanced Services with gpo or SCCM

Tags: sccm

We have an an application that doesn't work with 4.8 Advanced Services enabled. Turning it off through Control Panel is easy enough, but we have over 200 devices this software is going out to. Any help on how we might be able to accomplish this?

If we do it through add/remove features it doesn't prompt to reboot. So I'm trying to figure out how we can do this through SCCM and push it out to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commandline deinstallation of Windows Features can be done with dism.

```
Dism /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:<featurename>
```

would be the command. You can check all installed features with

```
DISM /online /get-features /format:table
```

I think the Advanced Services would probably be `Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-US-OC-Package` (Don't be confused when nothing is called 4.8, there is no way of having two 4.x installations in parallel so the UI will always be updated to reflect your currently installed version but the feature name stays the same)

Edit: I looked a little deeper into the matter and it seems the root node for  ".NET Framework 4.x Advanced Services" is probably `NetFx4-AdvSrvs`, the other one is just the sub node that is checked by default on a standard win 10 installation. Still keeping the info as it seemed to help but I think NetFx4-AdvSrvs would be the better call for disabling the feature completely.